# Current Python version (3.9.7) is not allowed by the project (^3.11)

Tags: python, python-poetry

We have a poetry project with a pyproject.toml file like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "daisy"
version = "0.0.2"
description = ""
authors = [""]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
pandas = "^1.5.2"
DateTime = "^4.9"
names = "^0.3.0"
uuid = "^1.30"
pyyaml = "^6.0"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.5"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.1"
pytest = "^7.2.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
jupyterlab = "^3.5.2"
line_profiler = "^4.0.2"
matplotlib = "^3.6.2"
seaborn = "^0.12.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I change the file to use Python 3.11 and run `poetry update` we get the following error:

```bash
Current Python version (3.9.7) is not allowed by the project (^3.11).
Please change python executable via the "env use" command.
```

I only have one env:

```bash
> poetry env list
daisy-Z0c0FuMJ-py3.9 (Activated)
```

Strangely this issue does not occur on my Macbook, only on our Linux machine.

Answer (score 4):

Poetry cannot update the Python version of an existing venv. Remove the existing one and run `poetry install` again.